# How to remove selected index of an array from the DOM and reflect the change in React state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my react app, I have an array of objects data that gets render to the table. The data structure of the data that I have is in the following format:

```
this.state = {
  inspectionViewAllRsData: [
    {
      INSPN_PERFORMER_CD: {label: "Contractor", value: "C"}
    },
    {
      INSPN_RSN_CD: {label: "Initial", value: "INIT"}
    },
    {
      INSPN_STS_CD: {label: "", value: "1000"}
    }
  ]
}
```

and here's my code for the table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Performed By</th>
    <th>Inspection</th>
    <th>Residence Size</th>
  </tr>
  {this.state.inspectionViewAllRsData.map((item, i) => (
    <tr>
      <td>{item.INSPN_PERFORMER_CD.label} <button id="close-btn" onClick={() => this.handleRemove(i)}>X</button></td>
      <td>{item.INSPN_RSN_CD.label}</td>
      <td>{item.RSDNC_SIZE_QTY.value}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

What I want to do is remove the selected index of an array from the state when I click on the "X" button. This is what I tried to do but it's giving me an error that `row.filter is not a function`

```
handleRemove = index => {
  const newData = this.state.inspectionViewAllRsData.map(row => {
    return row.filter((el, i) => i !== index);
  });
  console.log(newData)
  this.setState({ inspectionViewAllRsData: newData });
}
```

Can someone please help me with my functionality? Any help would be appreciate it.

Comment: What is `inspectionViewAllRsData`? Is it the data key from your first code block?

Comment: that's the name of my state array which I forgot to change in the post above. Thank you for noticing that.

Comment: Looking at the `this.state.inspectionViewAllRsData.map` I'm not convinced that the data structure in `inspectionViewAllRsData` is correct; each item in that map would be a thing like `{ INSPN_PERFORMER_CD: {label: "Contractor", value: "C"} }` whereas the component output in the map is expecting to be able to access `INSPN_RSN_CD` and `RSDNC_SIZE_QTY` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. You just tried to do too much, using `map` to `filter` on each individual element of the array - which isn't possible because these are objects, not arrays. You simple want a top-level filter. Replace the definition of `newData` with this and all should be fine:

```
const newData = this.state.inspectionViewAllRsData.filter((el, i) => i !== index);
```

Comment: Thank you Robin. I am no longer seeing an error message but the state data is still not getting removed the state. Any idea what might be an issue?

Comment: I finally got this working after moving my handleRemove handler to the parent component,  it started to work just fine. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you managed to render this, because it seems to me that you're confusing data structures and implementations.

In particular:

```
{this.state.inspectionViewAllRsData.map((item, i) => (
   <tr>
      <td>{item.INSPN_PERFORMER_CD.label} <button id="close-btn" onClick={() => this.handleRemove(i)}>X</button></td>
      <td>{item.INSPN_RSN_CD.label}</td>
      <td>{item.RSDNC_SIZE_QTY.value}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
```

Every `item` is something like:

```
{ 
   property: {label: "string", value: "string"} 
}
```

So you basically have an array of 3 elements which are `Object` type and you're trying to render them all when just one of them is selected by the `map` function.

I guess you meant to have an array of objects (`Object[]`) in which every single `Object` has 3 properties, so your "hard-coded" data should look like this:

```
inspectionViewAllRsData = [
   {
      INSPN_PERFORMER_CD: {label: "Contractor", value: "C"},
      INSPN_RSN_CD: {label: "Initial", value: "INIT"},
      INSPN_STS_CD: {label: "", value: "1000"}
   },
   // Other Objects with this structure
]
```

I hope what I wrote is clear enough and that I guessed your intentions right, if not, please tell me and I'll edit my answer.

**EDIT**

I think you should parse your input in a more easy to read/work with data structure.
This is my attempt and I'll try to explain my thought process.

In your state you should add another empty array:

```
this.state= {
   inspectionBlaBlah: //your initial data structure,
   newDataArray: []
}
```

In your constructor you should add an `Object` that will be useful to reorganize your data:

```
let toFillWithProperties = {};
```

After that u should do something like this:

```
inspectionViewAllRsData.map(
            // Cycle through your initial array
            (item, i) => {
                // Cycle through the properties of every item of your array
                return Object.keys(item).map(
                    (property, j) => {
                        // Create the same key/value for each property in your new object
                        toFillWithProperties[property] = item[property];
                        if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0){
                            // Every 3 steps you update your new Array
                            this.state.newDataArray.push(toFillWithProperties);
                            toFillWithProperties = {};
                        }
                    }
                )})
```

Once this is done you can then render the table like you were doing before but you should use the `map` function on `this.state.newDataArray`. The same applies for your handler function, use `setState` on your `newDataArray`.

It should work this way, but I really don't encourage you to work with this kind of data because this procedure is assuming that every 3 elements of your array they would repeat in structure, it won't work in any other cases.

Comment: Lucayam, you understood it correct. That's how the backend returns the data to the front-end (which I know is not in a good format) but that's what the structure for the api looks like coming from the backend. Is there any way that I can remove the selected table column from the UI on teh click of the button?

Comment: I think the only "easy" way to do it is to take your object retrieved from the API, save an empty object for later and then double cycle on the retrieved object. In every step of your inner cycle you should fill your empty object with the properties you have. Every 3 steps (0,1,2...and so on) you should push this object in another array, re-empty the object you have created and then continue the cycle.
I'll try to edit my answer and post some code about this.
I don't think it would be easy to render the structure like that if you don't do this.
P.S: change backend services :D

Comment: Thanks for all the help Lucayam. I finally got this working after moving my handleRemove handler to the parent component. Thanks for your help and time on this.